# Showing NSView with a button click

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I'm trying to write a program that draws a [Sierpinski Carpet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet), so user should choose the depth of recursion and click a button and then a window with the carpet should appear. 
But I'm a beginner so I don't know how to connect a button to a function that has a parameter **NSRect** . 
 
I have a MyView class (subclass of NSView)

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    if (b)
    draw(0, 0, 600, 600, 4);
}

void draw (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, int n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        NSRect rect0 = NSMakeRect (x1 + (x2 - x1)/3, y1 + (y2 - y1)/3, (x2 - x1)/3, (y2 - y1)/3);
        [[NSColor blackColor] set];
        NSRectFill(rect0);
    
        draw (x1                  , y1                  , x1 +   (x2 - x1)/3  , y1 +   (y2 - y1)/3  , n - 1);
    
        draw (x1                  , y1 +   (y2 - y1)/3  , x1 +   (x2 - x1)/3  , y1 + 2*(y2 - y1)/3  , n - 1);
    
        draw (x1                  , y1 + 2*(y2 - y1)/3  , x1 +   (x2 - x1)/3  , y2                  , n - 1);
    
        draw (x1 +   (x2 - x1)/3  , y1 + 2*(y2 - y1)/3  , x1 + 2*(x2 - x1)/3  , y2                  , n - 1);
    
        draw (x1 + 2*(x2 - x1)/3  , y1 + 2*(y2 - y1)/3  , x2                  , y2                  , n - 1);
    
        draw (x1 + 2*(x2 - x1)/3  , y1 +   (y2 - y1)/3  , x2                  , y1 + 2*(y2 - y1)/3  , n - 1);
    
        draw (x1 + 2*(x2 - x1)/3  , y1                  , x2                  , y1 +   (y2 - y1)/3  , n - 1);
    
        draw (x1 +   (x2 - x1)/3  , y1                  , x1 + 2*(x2 - x1)/3  , y1 +   (y2 - y1)/3  , n - 1);
    }
}

- (BOOL) isFlipped { return YES; }
```

I also have a NSTextField *depth (which is an IBOutlet) where user should type the depth of recursion

Thanks for your answers!:)

Comment: Just a few comments, but clicking a button shouldn't pass any parameter, but it should come from somewhere else like a text field. You can also 'hide' the view by using the method `isHidden:`, only showing it when necessary (when the button is clicked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass any arguments to methods that are connected to UIButtons (the most you can do is pass an int, using button.tag = 42).
So my suggestion to you is to connect your UIButton to a method like this,

```
- (IBAction)goButton:(id)sender {
    // Here you get the level of recursion that the user entered in the UITextField.
    NSString *recursionLevel = self.recuersionLevelOutlet.text; 

    // And do whatever you need to do with it.
    ...
}
```

To connect the UIButton to the view, if you're unsure, do the following.

1) Open the .xib file of the screen.

2) Open the .m file by holding<kbd>option</kbd> and clicking it's name (this will open it in the side pane).

3) While holding <kbd>control</kbd>, click on the UIButton and drag to an empty space between @interface YourViewController () and @end in you .m file.